# How to reboot Windows 7 safely in an automated way

Tags: windows-7

I have some Windows 7 PC's mainly doing the SW build

I am rebooting the PC every Sunday automatically (via Scheduler) using the following command

```
shutdown /r /f
```

This works mostly but in some case

- the PC's are rebooting and waiting in screen where it says the system was not shutdown properly and asks for option (normal boot, etc)
- The PC's are in shutdown state and need to hard reboot

Normally I don't have physical access to these machines and so it is hard when these machines aren't coming up

What is the safest way to reboot the Windows 7 PC in an automated way

Comment: Well I'm talking about the one comes after bios screen

Comment: OK - sorry, I didn't spot that.